# Count Number of cycles in graph/ plot using Python / Pandas / Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

How can I  find out how many times the Y value (Speed) ramps up and down from 700 -800 RPM to 1600 to 1800 RPM and vice versa from graph plotted in matplotlib by using python / pandas / numpy libraries. I have plotted this graph using matplotlib and using dataframe.

Expected output should be--->
Number of Ramps up in Speed  = 2 & Down = 2 looking at attached graph

Attached image /graph below for more clarification

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNP6M.png)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(18,10))

ax =plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(df.speed)

ax.set_yticks([0, 500, 700, 1000, 1500, 1700, 2000])

ax.set_xlabel("Time (Seconds)")
ax.set_ylabel("Speed (RPM)")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: what does `df.speed` look like? Is it just a list of integers?

Comment: Yes It's Just Integer value. Please see attached image file for more clarification.

Comment: @Analyst You could use the time derivative of your `df.speed` and only check how many times the sign has changed. I don't know how much jittering your real data has, but from the image it looks like the slopes are clean so that method could work.

Comment: @Guimoute: Real Data is too large and its complicated to understand if I plot here. That's why I have plotted graph  based on 1 day data.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': [0,1600,0,1600,1600,1600,0,0,0]})

# Check if values are above or below a threshold
threshold = 1500
df['over_threshold'] = df['speed'] > threshold

# Compare to the previous row
# If over_threshold has changed, 
# then you either went above or fell below the threshold
df['changed'] = df['over_threshold'] != df['over_threshold'].shift(1)

# First one has, by definition, has no previous value, so we should omit it
df = df.loc[1:,]

# Count how many times a row is newly above or below threshold
counts = df.loc[df['changed']].groupby('over_threshold').agg({'changed': 'count'})
counts.index = ["Down", "Up"]
counts.columns = ["Count"]
counts

#     Count
#Down   2
#Up     2
```

You will then have counts of how many times you have ramped up or down.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Your code works fine but I am not getting the expected result. It's giving me the total number of counts w.r.t each point (1 Second Data) in data frame. if you look at the attached graph then expected output should be...Number of ups = 2 and Number of Downs = 2.

Comment: I updated the code to include some dummy data and clarifying that the output shows 2 ramps up and 2 ramps down

Comment: Thanks,your code is right considering your df. I want to count the how many times speed Ups from 700RPM to 1600RPM and Speed downs from 1600RPM to 700RPM. If speed is increasing from 700 to 800  or  decreasing from 1600 to 1500 then it should not count an jump up i.e. "UP / DOWN = 0". If speed is increasing from 700 to 1600 with steps like 700, 900, 1400, 1600 then it should count "UP = 1" but not 3 and vice versa (It should not count in between increase or decrease in speed). If you look into attached image file you will get more clarification.

Comment: UP = 1 or Down =1 if and only if Difference in Speed is More than or equal to 900 RPM i.e  (1600 -700) RPM

Comment: e. g df = pd.DataFrame({'engspd': [0,500,700,1200,1200,1700,1700,1600,1600,700,600,800,800,900,600,700,700,1300,1800,1900,1900,1600,1600,1300,1300,1100,1100,700,700,700,0]})

For Above df expected output  should be : Up = 2 & Down =2

Answer (score 2):

```
# state variables
decreasing = False
increasing = False
last_above = False
last_below = False
drop_count = 0
jump_count = 0

for rpm_str in df:
    rpm = int(rpm_str)    # Because OP indicated the data was a string
    # Crossing threshold
    if ((last_below or decreasing) and rpm < 700):
        drop_count = drop_count + 1
        decreasing = False
        last_below = False
    elif ((last_above or increasing) and rpm > 1600):
        jump_count = jump_count + 1
        increasing = False
        last_above = False
    if (last_above and rpm < 1600):
        decreasing = True
        increasing = False
    elif (last_below and rpm > 700):
        increasing = True
        decreasing = False

    # State
    last_below = False
    last_above = False
    if (rpm < 700):
        last_below = True
    elif (rpm > 1600):
        last_above = True
```

This is not a perfect solution and will probably miss some edge cases, but your data looks pretty normal

Comment: You can pop the parenthesis in the `if` and also use a few `elif` here ;)

Comment: @Guimoute when it comes to state machines like this, I try to avoid elif because I often use them when I shouldn't, lol, but they would help here. Also, I like parenthesis 'cause I came from other languages, python wasn't my first.

Comment: @ZacharyOldham: My dataset is big but I am trying to count it over just 1 day data. If it works then I will use the similar logic to complete data.
      
I am trying to run the above script in Jupyter Notebook but I am having below error.! 

'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: It's probably something like `for rpm in df.speed` or `for rpm in df["speed"]`?

Comment: @Analyst are you reading the values from a file and not casting them?

Comment: @Guimoute: Thanks, Yeah I did that change  already and code is working.

Comment: @ZacharyOldham: Thanks, Your Code is Fine. It's working but It's not showing the the correct output for the new graphs I have attached.

Comment: @Analyst It looks like the graph is sitting just above the 700 threshold. Try upping it to 750. To confirm, you would expect 2 ramp-ups and 2 ramp-downs with that graph, yeah?

Comment: @ZacharyOldham: I tried changing the values of max & min rpm in code which you shared but still not giving the correct output which I am looking for!

Comment: @Analyst In the current graph you have linked, what is the output you are getting and what is the output you want?

Comment: @Analyst I updated the code to handle an edge case, can you check it now?

Comment: @ZacharyOldham: I am expecting the output as : Number of ramps up = 2 and down = 2. i.e Speed is continuously increasing from 700 rpm (approx) to 1950 rpm (approx) at 2 times and decreasing from 1950 rpm to 700 rpm at 2 times. It should not count the increase / decrease in speed you can observe in between from 700 to 1250 rpm and vice versa.

Comment: @ZacharyOldham: Yeah Sure I will check your new code as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ZacharyOldham: e. g df = pd.DataFrame({'engspd': [0,500,700,1200,1200,1700,1700,1600,1600,700,600,800,800,900,600,700,700,1300,1800,1900,1900,1600,1600,1300,1300,1100,1100,700,700,700,0]})

For Above df expected output  should be : Up = 2 & Down =2

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

`y` is the y data (rpm) `lim` is the amount of rpms at which a cycle has started

```
cycles = 0
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] >= lim:
        cycles += 1
        while y[i] >= lim:
            i += 1
```

Comment: `lim` does not exist yet when you test against it.